# Querying mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to query a collection in mongodb:

I want to find out the number of people who are sergeants in the police department?

My code -

```
db.EMPDETAILS.find({$and: [{Job Titles: "SERGEANT"}, {Department: "POLICE"}]}).count()
```

Table structure looks like this- ( mongo imported a csv file-)-

```
> db.EMPDETAILS.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa981"), "Name" : "ALLISON,  PAUL W", "Job Titles" : "LIEUTENANT", "Department" : "FIRE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$107790.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa982"), "Name" : "BRUNO,  KEVIN D", "Job Titles" : "SERGEANT", "Department" : "POLICE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$104628.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa983"), "Name" : "COOPER,  JOHN E", "Job Titles" : "LIEUTENANT-EMT", "Department" : "FIRE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$114324.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa984"), "Name" : "CRESPO,  VILMA I", "Job Titles" : "STAFF ASST", "Department" : "LAW", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$76932.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa985"), "Name" : "DOLAN,  ROBERT J", "Job Titles" : "SERGEANT", "Department" : "POLICE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$111474.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa986"), "Name" : "DUBERT,  TOMASZ ", "Job Titles" : "PARAMEDIC I/C", "Department" : "FIRE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$91080.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5927455eb048747c01baa987"), "Name" : "EDWARDS,  TIM P", "Job Titles" : "LIEUTENANT", "Department" : "FIRE", "Full or Part-Time" : "F", "Salary or Hourly" : "Salary", "Typical Hours" : "", "Annual Salary" : "$114846.00", "Hourly Rate" : "" }
```

I am new to MongoDB. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `.find({ "Job Titles": "SERGEANT", "Department": "POLICE"})`. Note the quotes `""` especially around the key name with a **space** in it. Also you almost never need `$and`. **ALL** Query arguments are already AND conditions, unless you are explicitly calling an `$or`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Neil, I ran it without the $and as you mentioned and it works perfectly. Something I was not aware of. Thanks for the help.